# javascript undefined variable - doesn't seem like it?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the long code, but my environment does not support script tags.

http://pastebin.ca/2105293

I try to call loadbang (line 976) and get

```
_r.Multistrokes[z].name is undefined
```

I thought I defined it right there in the function, no?

Comment: Please always put the relevant code and such *in the question itself*. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question Also, you'll have to trim it down a bit.

Comment: Where are you defining a name property?

Comment: kinakuta: line 100

TJ: All due respectbut I really have no idea how. I'm open to suggestios re what you consider relevant to the problem and what you consider irrelevant

Comment: @jamesson: In this case, to trim it down you'd extract the `Multistroke` constructor and the `NDollarRecognizer` constructor and the most minimal code you could to create an `NDollarRecognizer` and demonstrate the problem. Creating the simplest replicating test case is one of the key debugging techniques for a developer. 90% of the time, when you do that, you find the problem. The remaining 10% of the time, you have something nice and small and isolated you can use to ask for help from your peers (or here on SO).

Comment: Thanks for the wisdom, TJ. Excellent advice which I will endeavor to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Multistroke` constructor function (it's not a "class") sets the `Name` property on the object (line 103):

```
this.Name = name;
```

But on line 1,000, you're trying to use the `name` property (note the difference in capitalization):

```
strokeName[z]=_r.Multistrokes[z].name.toString
```

JavaScript is case-sensitive.

---

Side note: Line 1,000 also has the issue that you're not actually *calling* `toString`, you're assigning the function reference to `strokeName[z]`. To actually *call* it, add `()` to the end of `toString`.

Side note 2: The code relies heavily on the abomination that is JavaScript's [automatic semicolon insertion](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9). Strongly recommend **not** relying on it, and putting in all necessary semicolons explicitly. Relying on ASI makes minification difficult, and can introduce subtle bugs.

Comment: thanks so much... I feel dumb now

For whatever reason I thought I needed to reference the original args.

Comment: @jamesson: I modified the first side note. Note that you're not *casting* it. JavaScript doesn't have casting, because it doesn't have strong typing. You're (potentially) *converting* it from whatever it is to a string. (But surely, looking at `Multistroke`, it's a string already?) `toString` is a perfectly reasonable way to do that, but you have to *call* the function (see the answer). Another way is to use the `String` function without `new`, like this: `strokeName[z]=String(_r.Multistrokes[z].name);` When you use `String` without `new`, it does a type conversion.

Comment: toString now works like a dream. Thanks for the assist and the debugging suggestions. StackExchange Rocks!

Comment: The support for javascript in the environment I'm working in may be charitably described as kludgy. This is why the type conversion is necessary. Without it, environment handles it as a memory pointer believe it or not.

Comment: re semicolons, I'm a little close to deadline alas. I'll prettify the code when I have a moment. Definitely keep it in mind in the future tho.

Answer (score 1):

In `Multistrokes` you have field `Name` not `name`.

Constructor:

```
function Multistroke(name, useBoundedRotationInvariance, strokes) // constructor
{
    this.Name = name;this.Name = name;
    [...]
}
```

Access:

```
strokeName[z]=_r.Multistrokes[z].name.toString
```